# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: json

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to deploy my first Spark Application on our new cluster, but I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: json. Please find packages at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:249)
at de.wlw.mad.company_analyser.util.WebPageReader$.apply(WebPageReader.scala:9)
at de.wlw.mad.company_analyser.Analyse$.sparkCommand(Analyse.scala:54)
at de.wlw.mad.company_analyser.Analyse$.apply(Analyse.scala:171)
at de.wlw.mad.company_analyser.AnalysisWorker$.listen(AnalysisWorker.scala:18)
at de.wlw.mad.bunny.AbstractListener$1.handleDelivery(AbstractListener.java:46)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:144)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: json.DefaultSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:132)
```

I have written some Tests for my Spark Code, and they are running successfully. My pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Hadoop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Scala Lib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

object WebPageReader {
  def apply(spark: SparkSession, path: String): Dataset[WebPageCase] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    spark.read.json(path).as[WebPageCase]
  }
}
```

WebPageCase is a Scala Case Class

The Cluster in running in the cloud. Using bin/spark-submit, I get the same error as running the job from my local environment. The Spark Master and Workers are build without Hadoop.

What Package am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Try to directly run small test on the spark master with spark-shell

Comment: After some DNS issues, I was able to start the shell. But the Application still can't be run.

Comment: After some debugging, I get the code running inside my IDE, but after Building the jar, the code still was raising this givien error.

I changed the code to read from a csv file and map the results by my self using the case class. 

      `val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)
      val elements = rdd.map(line => line.split(";"))
      elements.map(element => {
        val id = element(0)
        WebPageCase(id)`


This worked also with a jar file. Probably someone still can help?